# Unit testing and mocking domain objects

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a domain class, which looks like this:

```
public class Employee
{
    public Guid EmployeeId { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Surname { get; private set; }
    ...
    // other properties

    public ICollection<Language> Languages { get; private set; }
        = new List<Language>();

    public ICollection<Skill> Skills { get; private set; }
        = new List<Skill>();

    public void AddLanguage(Language language)
    {
        if (language == null)
            return;

        Languages.Add(language);
    }

    public void DeleteLanguage(Guid languageId)
    {
        var languageToDelete = Languages
            .SingleOrDefault(x => x.LanguageId == languageId);

        if(languageToDelete == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Language entry doesn't exist.");

        Languages.Remove(languageToDelete);
    }
}
```

I would like to test given methods but I'm stuck.

I have:

```
    [Fact]
    public void AddLanguage_AfterCallWithValidObject_LanguagesCollectionContainsAddedObject()
    {
        var language = new Mock<Language>();
        var employee = new Employee("Name", "Surname", ...);

        employee.AddLanguage(language.Object);

        Assert.Contains(employee.EmployeeLanguages, x => x.Language.Equals(language.Object));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void DeleteLanguage_WhenLanguageWithGivenIdDoesntExist_ThrowArgumentException()
    {
        var languageToDelete = new Language("English");

        var employee = new Mock<Employee>();
        employee.Setup(x => x.Languages).Returns(new List<Languages>
        {
            new Language("Spanish"),
            new Language("German")
        });

        employee.Object.DeleteLanguage(languageToDelete);

        // Asserts here
    }
```

In the first test I would like also assert that **Languages.Add(skill)** method was called but I have no idea how to do it.

1. Is it an elegant way to do it? I thought about mocking **Add** method but I'm not sure if it is a good idea.

In the second test I cannot simply mock **Employee** object as it is not an interface.
I thought about exposing **Employee** but I read I should not do that just for testing purpose.

2. How should I mock **Languages** property without exposing **Employee** as interface? Is it possible? Is it any good practice to do this kind of things?
3. Is my general concept for test these methods is okay? (I'm new in unit testing)

Comment: Assuming you are using Moq, you would have to make those methods virtual, and then create a mock of the domain object, do a proper `Setup` on the method(s), and then assert with a call to `Verify`.

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful.

Comment: why even mock this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should tests objects as "black box" without relying on implementation details. In your case implementation details is that `Employee` class uses `ICollection.Add` method.

And you definitely don't need to mock at all in your case.
**Mock only dependencies which will make tests slow or very very very very complex to configure for the test.**

```
[Fact]
public void AddLanguage_ShouldSaveGivenLanguage()
{
    var language = new Language();
    var employee = new Employee("Name", "Surname");

    employee.AddLanguage(language);

    var expectedLanguages = new[] { language };
    employee.EmployeeLanguages.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedLanguages);
}
```

Use public API `Employee` class provide to setup it for the test (back box).
For testing `DeleteLanguage` add dummy languages through public API of the class.

```
[Fact]
public void DeleteLanguage_WhenLanguageExists_Remove()
{
    var language1 = new Language("German");
    var language2 = new Language("French");
    var languageToDelete = new Language("English");

    var employee = new Employee("Name", "Surname");
    employee.AddLanguage(language1);
    employee.AddLanguage(language2);
    employee.AddLanguage(languageToDelete);

    employee.DeleteLanguage(languageToDelete);

    var expectedLanguages = new[] { language1, language2 };
    employee.EmployeeLanguages.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedLanguages);
}

[Fact]
public void DeleteLanguage_WhenLanguageNotExists_ThrowException()
{
    var language1 = new Language("German");
    var language2 = new Language("French");
    var notExistedLanguage = new Language("English");

    var employee = new Employee("Name", "Surname");
    employee.AddLanguage(language1);
    employee.AddLanguage(language2);

    Action delete = () => employee.DeleteLanguage(languageToDelete);

    delete.Should()
          .Throw<ArgumentException>()
          .WithMessage("Language entry doesn't exist.");
}
```

Did you notice how cumbersome `employee.EmployeeLanguages` reads, you can rename property to just `employee.Languages`.

For readable assertions I used [FluentAssertions library](https://fluentassertions.com/documentation/)

Answer (score 1):

For domain objects with very simple behavior and no dependencies, mocking isn't strictly needed. You can test `Add` simply with this:

```
//Arrange
var e = new Employee();
var l = new Mock<Language>(); 

//Act
e.AddLanguage(l.Object);

//Assert
Assert.IsTrue(e.Languages.Contains(l.Object));
```

Testing in this fashion you can achieve perfectly good code coverage and plenty of confidence that the Employee class works as designed.